# Run two programs at the same time C/C++

Tags: c++, c, compilation, ipc

I was reading [this](https://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node25.html) article about Inter-Process communication with message passing. In order to run the examples and see the it says and I quote: "should be compiled and run at the same time". Someone has any ideas how exactly should I do this?

Comment: 1. Compile and run one. 2. Without stopping the first one, compile and run the other? -- Alternatively, it could mean: 1. Compile both. 2. Run one. 3. Without stopping the first one, run the other. (because English is weird like that)

Comment: If you're on Linux, fork() and exec() in conjunction would allow you to run two different executable files at the same time, but there's no way you could execute a program while compiling it. There are probably similar functions in Windows and other non-POSIX operating systems.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how you are supposed to run a program while it is still compiling. There might be a grammar error in that quote somewhere...

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, that's another possible meaning (because English is weird like that). I didn't consider that one because it's obviously stupid.

Comment: @immibis No weirder than `++i + i++`. When I see grammar like that I have to worry about the code quality. For one thing, if an IPC example requires two programs to be running simultaneously, that should be expected. If they both have to be started simultaneously, there's a design fault in there somewhere. The code samples don't look stupid at a quick glance, so I think the English grammar is just lazy.

Comment: The article means that both programs should be compiled first, then after both are compiled, run them at the same time. As answered below, you can create a batch file to run both program at about the same time. Normally, with a multi-process application, one of the processes will setup any shared memory and synchronization stuff that needs to be done, then it starts the other process.

Answer (score 0):

You can create BAT file and start both programs almost simultaneously:

```
START first.exe
START second.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

> "should be compiled and run at the same time"

I think it is clear a program can not be run until after it is compiled (this is a minor grammatical issue, and should be ignored).

---

In Linux, my preferred mechanism to launch a process is popen invoked by my C++ program.

In C++, it is easy for one thread (let us call this your start process) to use popen to launch as many processes as needed for your application (call these work processes).

I would then use messages to synchronize the start up (i.e. work processes should initialize themselves, then wait (at startup) for a go message from start process).  These start up messages work in the same way your application would use them.  This ensures that the multiple work processes are running at the same time (but within the constraints of how many cores your system has available).